# Typo3 get content from another Extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I had an extension called "mbl_newsevent" that work with tt_news. The newsevent ext has his own TS and generates a register button on every news if i enable it. Now the newesevent ext generates a button with a url that contains the current tt_news id.

TS config part:

```
plugin.tt_news.mbl_newsevent {
    registrationLink_typolink {
        title.data = LLL:EXT:mbl_newsevent/locallang.xml:registerLinkLabel
        parameter = {$powermail.plugin.pid}
        parameter.override.field = tx_mblnewsevent_regurl
        additionalParams.field = uid
        additionalParams.intval = 1
        additionalParams.wrap = &tx_powermail_pi1[eventUid]=|
            #this returns the correct ID of tt_news for example 99
    }
}
```

But now i need this eventUid in another location of my basic TS. I need this eventUid for my second menu as a parameter

Basic TS:

```
2 = TMENU
2 {
    wrap = <ul class="naviMainLevel2"> | </ul>

    NO {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>
    }
    ACT = 1
    ACT {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active"> | </li>                
            additionalParams.data = GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news
            additionalParams.intval = 1
            #Here is the part where i need the id from tt_news.mbl_newsevent
                #atm it returns &tx_events_pi1[newsUid]=0 correct id would be for example 99
                additionalParams.wrap = &tx_events_pi1[newsUid]=|
    }
    CUR = 1
    CUR < .ACT

}
```

How can i access to another Database (Extension) to get the same id?

```
temp.xyz = RECORDS
temp.xyz {
    tables = tt_news.mbl_newsevent 
    ...
}
```

Comment: So, you would have tx_events_pi1[newsUid]= tt_news.mbl_newsevent of the News which is defined via GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news?

Comment: Why don't you use ``additionalParams.stdWrap < plugin.tt_news.mbl_newsevent.registrationLink_typolink`` and an additional wrap for the ``&tx_events_pi[newsUid]=``